# ListBox with pop-out/popup item details

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a listbox, with a details pop-up/tooltip kind of window.
Scenario is as following:

- List of items
- Show details of selected item
- Details should be displayed outside the listbox and overlaying any controls that happens to be nearby.

The problem about using tooltips is that they disappear after a while. And the problem about using pop-ups is that they do not move, when the window moves (?)

So I'm just looking for some pointers on how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ToolTip object. It has autopositioning and nice graphical style out of the box.

Simply use it like this:

```
        toolTip.PlacementTarget = yourSelectedItem;
        toolTip.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
        toolTip.Content = {place whatever you need to display here};
```

You can control its visibility with the IsOpen property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will try both of your suggestions with newly aquired knowledge.

Comment: I think IsOpen is a readonly property. I dont think this will work.

Comment: It isn't. And it works. I'm using it like this in my app. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.isopen.aspx

Comment: You are right!!! And it also has a StaysOpen property. This will indeed work. Is there a way to use it in XAML I couldnt find it. I probably dont know the correct syntax...

Comment: I don't think this can be done purely in XAML, but I might be wrong. Back when I was using this code, I didn't use XAML as all (it was just one WPF control for WinForms app).

Comment: I solved the problem using tooltips as you suggested. I also tried NVM's suggestion using pop-ups, but windows was left all over the place =). 

I also discovered the ToolTipService and with the following configuration I got the behaviour I wanted;

                                        ToolTipService.Placement="Left"
                                        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="100"
                                        ToolTipService.HasDropShadow="True"
                                        ToolTipService.ShowDuration="30000"

Answer (score 1):

Adorners were built for things like these.

That said, if I were doing this I would set "StaysOpen" on a Popup to false. So when the user clicks somewhere else it will automatically disappear (ie when window is moved). Do you really see your users moving the window so often **while** looking at the details? Going down the adorners route is not all that easy. It has its own complications.

Comment: Good idea. No they don't generally move their window around. But if they did, it would look very dumb.

Comment: heh, funny if you set the StaysOpen to false. It stays open even if you move the window around. Click on the chrome is not intercepted

Comment: You probably have something else setting it back to IsOpen. I just did a quick check and a click on window chrome most certainly hides it.

Comment: Add some source and I might be able to give you a better answer. I've done something similar on a couple of ocassions previously so I am certain that this approach works.

Comment: Yes it works, but it requires a bit more work to tweak the pop-up behaviour. The tooltip has done this for me. So by using it, I was able to complete the task a bit faster.

The pop-up gives superior control and possibilities and I will look into it if I encounter a similar scenario in the future. Thanks a lot.